# "Ich werde langweilig" and "mir ist langweilig"

Tags: difference

Does "Ich werde langweilig" mean the same as "Mir ist langweilig"?

> ***Mir ist langweilig***, wenn ich hier sitze und nichts mache.
>
> ***Ich werde langweilig,*** wenn wir vom selben Grammatikproblem die ganze Zeit reden.

Comment: Um... just a small question: have you even tried to translate these sentences back?? You ask the difference of become and be here...

Comment: I wanted to know if they all mean the same translation ' i am getting bored'

Comment: Why not ask that instead? Actually now that I think about it, this is a common problem with your questions. You don't give us anything we can relate to, you just place two phrases, which are of differing "unequality", and don't tell us your thought process behind the problem....

Comment: Next time, i'll do it :)

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: the way this site works best is to  take appropriate action whenever you are asked for improvements or clarification via comments. This should then be done by an [edit] to your question. Comments or a *"promise to do it next time"* will not make the present question better ;)

Comment: "Ich werde langweilig" ist kein Deutsch. Das ist Englisch Wort für Wort ins Deutsche übersetzt. Das haut in den meisten Fällen nicht hin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

> Mir ist langweilig

means "to me (it) is boring", or in idiomatic English "I am bored"

> Ich werde langweilig/Ich bin langweilig

on the other hand means "I am becoming boring/I am boring"

---

As Hans pointed out, if you wanted to say "I am getting bored" it'd be

> Mir wird langweilig.

---

I dunno if this is correct but I think

> Mir ist langweilig, wenn ich hier sitze und nichts mache

would be better as

> Es langweilt mich, hier zu sitzen und nichts zu machen.

Comment: I like the active form of your last example better. But it may be a sentiment on my side, as the second form sounds like the speaker is about to do something about that boredom, while the passive form is just whining. Anyway, both are entirely valid and idiomatic german sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Du kannst nicht "Ich werde langweilig" sagen, aber Folgendes:

> Mir wird langweilig

Comment: Yes, we can say "Ich werde langweilig"... I just did just that. I turned 33.

Comment: but not in this context ! If you want to say that you get boring for others!