# Jemandem langweilig sein

Tags: adjective, dative

1. What phrase is correct for the english meaning "he is very bored"?

> Es ist ihm sehr langweilig.

> Ihm ist sehr langweilig.

2. "Der Film war mir sehr langweilig." Is this phrase grammatically correct?

If so, does it mean "I was bored by the film"?

If not, how to express "I was bored by the film" other than "der Film langweilte mich"?

Comment: There are a couple of related questions; ["Ich werde langweilig" and "mir ist langweilig"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9215/43989) seems most relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence *Es ist ihm sehr langweilig* uses what I call the point-of-view dative. ([This site](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dative-reference)  uses the same term but for Latin.) The *es* here is an impersonal pronoun and in this case it stands for conditions in general; it's the same role played by "it" in "It's cold." The *ihm* says that the statement is only true according to "his" point of view. Literally, it says "It is, to him, very boring." Apparently boredom, to German speakers, is a quality of the environment and not individual people. German flexible word order allows you to move *ihm* in front of the verb, so you can rephrase the sentence as *Ihm ist es sehr langweilig.* The *es* is really just a placeholder, and since it's no longer need for V2 word order, it can be dropped, giving *Ihm ist sehr langweilig.* (The impersonal *es* is very prone to being left out, but in some situations more than others. So both versions are correct, but I think the second one is more idiomatic German.

I believe *Der Film war mir sehr langweilig* is grammatically correct, but there are alternatives. There is a verb *langweilen* you can use if something is boring someone. This is grammatically different from the adjective *langweilig*. So *Der Film langweilte mich* is possible, but I think the participle, *Der Film hat mich gelangweilt,* would be a more common phrasing. The English "I was bored by the film" is technically in the passive voice, so rendering it literally into German you'd get, *Ich wurde von dem Film gelangweilt.* But I think a somewhat looser translation would work better: *Ich fand den Film langweilig.*/"I found the movie boring."

Comment: *Ich fand den Film langweilig* would also be my first choice.

Comment: To be honest: Nobody would say "Der Film war mir sehr langweilig", even if it is grammatically correct. The usual way to phrase this would be something like what RDBury said "Ich fand den Film langweilig", or even "Der Film war langweilig"

Comment: I would regard _Der Film war mir sehr langweilig_ as wrong. I think, you are mistaken when it comes to interpreting the _es_ in the construction _Es ist jmdm. sehr langweilig_. This construction is rather uncommon, one would rather say _Jmdm. ist sehr langweilig_. When it is used, the _es_ does not refer to some abstract entity (as the environment) but is simply an expletive _es_. See https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Expletivum#/Expletive_im_Deutschen. So, I think your answer is actually wrong. Hence I give -1 here.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: I think this is mainly a matter of terminology. There are many uses of *es*, and I'm using "impersonal *es*" to refer to any use other than as the "personal *es*", *es* as a personal pronoun. To me, having different terminology for "Impersonal" and "expletive" is unnecessarily complicated, especially since "expletive" has a different meaning in English. I've found it an ongoing problem that grammars designed for learners tend to be incomplete, but grammars intended for German speakers tend to be mired in linguistic jargon, so I often create my own terminology.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: PS. I'm not sure why you think *Der Film war mir sehr langweilig* is wrong. I assume your ear for incorrect German grammar is much better than mine, but I don't see what would make the sentence ungrammatical. I agree that it would not be idiomatic phrasing. You could also say that "To me, the film was very boring" is not how you would phrase the meaning in English, but I think it's still grammatically correct.

Comment: I think it is "wrong" in the sense that no German speaker I know would use this. Of course, my judgement is based on my limited of the German language. Maybe it is common in some dialect or sociolect which I don't know. Whether you call it "ungrammatically" or "not idiomatic" is a difference I would not be able to define here. It is just not how people talk. One would say _Der Film langweilt mich_ or _Ich finde den Film langweilig_.

Comment: Regarding the _es_:  I totally agree, that the _es_ is very similar in _es regnet_. I think the idea is wrong that the _es_ would be representing anything (the "environment" in your case). It has no meaning, and is just there for grammatical reasons - because the sentence needs a subject in first position. (The same is true for _es regnet_, btw.: There is really _nothing_ that does the raining, neither personal nor impersonal.)